# can you do an optional match if a parameter exists in neo4j cypher?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

When users are authenticated, I want to extend my cypher query to include whether a user has a `:LIKED` relationship to an item node, and include this in my projection as a boolean value.

if the user is authenticated I will supply a `{userId}`, alternatively the `{userId}` param will be null.  I've investigated `WHERE`, and `exists` but this doesn't seem like the right approach.

Is this possible in cypher at all currently?

EDIT:

This seems to be possible using the `OPTIONAL MATCH` in my first tests, but is this the correct approach?

```
  MATCH (m:Media {mediaId: {itemId}})
  WITH m, labels(m) as labels
    OPTIONAL MATCH (m)<-[r:LIKED]-(:Person {userId: {userId}})
    RETURN m { .*, labels, liked: exists(properties(r).createdAt) } AS result
      LIMIT 1
```

Lastly, I may have several relationships, that could only be present if the user making the request is authenticated, and the userId param is nit `NULL`.

any suggestions or improvements would be fantastic from more experienced cypher users.

Comment: essentially I'm trying to avoid writing multiple versions of the same query

Comment: additionally I'm concerned about doing this in an idiomatic way that will allow for the best performance.

Comment: Can you show the entire query?

Comment: @cybersam - I've addedd it, though I'm uncertain of the relevance.  As mentioned, the above works, provided the userId param is provided with NULL or a string value,  but I'm interested in whether this is the NEO4J way, and the most efficient way to handle this requirement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[EDITED]

If you do not need to test for the existence of the `createdAt` property, then this even simpler query would work:

```
MATCH (m:Media {mediaId: $itemId})
RETURN m { .*, labels:labels(m),
  liked: EXISTS((m)<-[:LIKED]-(:Person {userId: $userId})) } AS result;
```

Comment: Hi there, and thanks, I think the first one misses the objective, I'm trying to show the user who is viewing an index page, whether or not they have 'liked' an item.  The second feels closer to what I'm after, I assume, if there were multiple relationships like this (liked, commentedOn, playedRecently) we could move it to a WITH clause

Comment: I'd like to test before marking this as correct, can you speak to any other aspects of the question ie: performance?

Comment: okay, so the first query suggested here does not fit the requirements,  it filters the results and counts the number of people who liked it, (leaving us with only items that were liked), the second one seems to be closer to correct, though I'd like to profile this against the optional match.  could update your answer, please?

Comment: What is an "index page"? I am not sure what you are trying to do. Can you amend your question?

Comment: in this instance, I'm referring to a listing page of items.  these items could be viewed by unauthenticated users.  when a user is authenticated the `userId` will not be NULL, and in that instance, I want add a boolean value to the item based on whether  they have a relationship of `LIKED`.  if the userId is null, then this projected property should be false.

Comment: could you please update your answer to exclude the first query and aggregation as this does not solve the problem, but your second query does.  So that I can mark this as correct.  Thanks!